# Quillen–Suslin theorem in a more general context

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, koszul-duality, koszul-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional local Frobenius algebra that is Koszul.

> Question: Is it true for the Koszul dual of $A$ that every finitely generated projective module is free? If not, is there a criterion when it is true for such $A$?

For example for $A$ the exterior algebra, the Koszul dual is the polynomial ring where the question is true by the Quillen–Suslin theorem.

Comment: Do you know any non-exterior example?